# how to use wordpress upload file/image code in my plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin and I need to have a field where I can upload an image. Since wordpress has a very handly uploader it would be great if I could use that.

anyone know if that's possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about this, how to use the drop down media uploader from Wordpress :) http://www.cedricve.me/2012/03/31/use-the-built-in-wordpress-uploader-in-your-own-wp-plugin/ Hope this wil help you or someone else. Have a nice day

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only want to upload a file, you don't need the media uploader. A simple form is all you need.

To call the media uploader you need a link like this:

```
<a onclick="return false;" title="Upload image" class="thickbox" id="add_image" href="media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;width=640&amp;height=105">Upload Image</a>
```

You'll maybe have to append your URL to media-upload.php to make it working.

Comment: >>> You'll maybe have to append your URL to media-upload.php to make it working.

how do I do that?

Comment: Just use <?php echo bloginfo('name') ?>/wp-admin/media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;width=640&amp;height=105 for the href attribute which will include the blogs url and the wp-admin folder were the media-upload.php is located.

Comment: What is your plugin going to do? I have written 3 plugins myself. Maybe your plugin might be useful for me. And did you know that you can vote up a answer AND accept it ;)

Comment: If i'm using this on a plugin, how can i get the uploaded image url for use?

Comment: I never used it inside of a plugin myself. So I really can't tell how to do that. But you might find an anwser in the codex.

Comment: Found it, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11235/how-to-get-the-image-url-from-media-upload-in-a-post/11254

Comment: From WP 3.5 onwards there this method can be called deprecated

Answer (score 6):

YOu can use wordpress default media file uploader by using this code and simply retrieve link of image in jquery

```
<label for="upload_image">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" /> 
    <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>

<?php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts() {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/my-admin.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');
    }
}

?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: true
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            console.log(custom_uploader.state().get('selection').toJSON());
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
    </script>
```

Comment: added two more lines and displaying the selected image as a thumbnail.
<img id="upload_image_src" src="http://" height="250"  width="250" />

$('#upload_image_src').attr('src',attachment.url);

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following code,

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit_image_selector'] ) && isset( $_POST['image_attachment_id'] ) ) :
        update_option( 'media_selector_attachment_id', absint( $_POST['image_attachment_id'] ) );
    endif;
    wp_enqueue_media();
    ?><form method='post'>
        <div class='image-preview-wrapper'>
            <img id='image-preview' src='<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_option( 'media_selector_attachment_id' ) ); ?>' width='200'>
        </div>
        <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Upload image' ); ?>" />
        <input type='hidden' name='image_attachment_id' id='image_attachment_id' value='<?php echo get_option( 'media_selector_attachment_id' ); ?>'>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_image_selector" value="Save" class="button-primary">
    </form>
<?php
$my_saved_attachment_post_id = get_option( 'media_selector_attachment_id', 0 );
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            // Uploading files
            var file_frame;
            var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
            var set_to_post_id = <?php echo $my_saved_attachment_post_id; ?>; // Set this
            jQuery('#upload_image_button').on('click', function( event ){
                event.preventDefault();
                // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
                if ( file_frame ) {
                    // Set the post ID to what we want
                    file_frame.uploader.uploader.param( 'post_id', set_to_post_id );
                    // Open frame
                    file_frame.open();
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Set the wp.media post id so the uploader grabs the ID we want when initialised
                    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
                }
                // Create the media frame.
                file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    title: 'Select a image to upload',
                    button: {
                        text: 'Use this image',
                    },
                    multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
                });
                // When an image is selected, run a callback.
                file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
                    // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
                    attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
                    $( '#image-preview' ).attr( 'src', attachment.url ).css( 'width', 'auto' );
                    $( '#image_attachment_id' ).val( attachment.id );
                    // Restore the main post ID
                    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
                });
                    // Finally, open the modal
                    file_frame.open();
            });
            // Restore the main ID when the add media button is pressed
            jQuery( 'a.add_media' ).on( 'click', function() {
                wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
            });
        });
</script>
```